# How to automate release drafting from archive uploaded by the `actions/upload-artifact@v3` action?

Tags: github-actions, unzip

I'm currently attempting to automate the creation of GitHub releases.
The [automation I attempted to use here](https://github.com/freylint/relaymono/blob/324a811274035dc2ad425f1b9e7c8e2fd8e9ef74/.github/workflows/qaftray-publish.yml#L99):

```
  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    needs: build
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: release_artifacts
          path: ${{ github.workspace }}/release_artifacts.zip

      - name: Extract artifacts for release upload
        run: |
          mkdir ${{ github.workspace }}/pkg
          ls ${{ github.workspace }}
          unzip ${{ github.workspace }}/release_artifacts.zip -d ${{ github.workspace }}/pkg/
```

runs into an issue where it cannot find archive that the ls command and absolute path clearly show exists in this log:

```
> mkdir /home/runner/work/relaymono/relaymono/pkg
> ls /home/runner/work/relaymono/
pkg
release_artifacts.zip
> unzip /home/runner/work/relaymono/relaymono/release_artifacts.zip -d /home/runner/work/relaymono/relaymono/pkg/
unzip:  cannot find or open /home/runner/work/relaymono/relaymono/release_artifacts.zip, /home/runner/work/relaymono/relaymono/release_artifacts.zip.zip or /home/runner/work/relaymono/relaymono/release_artifacts.zip.ZIP.
Error: Process completed with exit code 9.
```

I've tried several permutations of paths starting with relative paths and ending where it is now.
I expected that the unzip script here would result in extracting the release_artifacts.zip archive into the pkg/ dir, allowing them to be updated to the later release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please notice that download step already unzipped your zip file

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 runner docker 4096 Aug 14 06:58 pkg
drwxr-xr-x 2 runner docker 4096 Aug 14 06:58 release_artifacts.zip
```